# F#, FParsec, and Calling a Stream Parser Recursively

Tags: f#, multipart, fparsec

I'm developing a multi-part MIME parser using F# and FParsec. I'm developing iteratively, and so this is highly unrefined, brittle code--it only solves my first immediate problem. Red, Green, Refactor.

I'm required to parse a stream rather than a string, which is really throwing me for a loop. Given that constraint, to the best of my understanding, I need to call a parser recursively. How to do that is beyond my ken, at least with the way I've proceeded thus far.

```
namespace MultipartMIMEParser

open FParsec
open System.IO

type private Post = { contentType : string
                    ; boundary    : string
                    ; subtype     : string
                    ; content     : string }

type MParser (s:Stream) =
  let ($) f x = f x
  let ascii = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII
  let str cs = System.String.Concat (cs:char list)
  let q = "\""
  let qP = pstring q
  let pSemicolon = pstring ";"
  let manyNoDoubleQuote = many $ noneOf q
  let enquoted = between qP qP manyNoDoubleQuote |>> str
  let skip = skipStringCI
  let pContentType = skip "content-type: "
                     >>. manyTill anyChar (attempt $ preturn () .>> pSemicolon)
                     |>> str
  let pBoundary = skip " boundary=" >>. enquoted
  let pSubtype = opt $ pSemicolon >>. skip " type=" >>. enquoted
  let pContent = many anyChar |>> str // TODO: The content parser needs to recurse on the stream.
  let pStream = pipe4 pContentType pBoundary pSubtype pContent
                      $ fun c b t s -> { contentType=c; boundary=b; subtype=t; content=s }
  let result s = match runParserOnStream pStream () "" s ascii with
                 | Success (r,_,_) -> r
                 | Failure (e,_,_) -> failwith (sprintf "%A" e)
  let r = result s
  member p.ContentType = r.contentType
  member p.Boundary = r.boundary
  member p.ContentSubtype = r.subtype
  member p.Content = r.content
```

The first line of the example POST follows:

`content-type: Multipart/related; boundary="RN-Http-Body-Boundary"; type="multipart/related"`

It spans a single line in the file. Further sub-parts in the content include `content-type` values that span multiple lines, so I know I'll have to refine my parsers if I am to reuse them.

Somehow I've got to call `pContent` with the (string?) results of `pBoundary` so that I can split the rest of the stream on the appropriate boundaries, and then somehow return multiple parts for the content of the post, each of which will be a separate post, with headers and content (which will obviously have to be something other than a string). My head is spinning. This code already seems far too complex to parse a single line.

Much appreciation for insight and wisdom!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fragment that might get you going in the right direction.

Get your parsers to spit out something with the same base type.  I prefer to use F#'s discriminated unions for this purpose.  If you really do need to push values into a Post type, then walk the returned AST tree.  That's just the way I'd approach it.

```
#if INTERACTIVE
#r"""..\..\FParsecCS.dll"""    // ... edit path as appropriate to bin/debug, etc.
#r"""..\..\FParsec.dll"""
#endif

let packet = @"content-type: Multipart/related; boundary=""RN-Http-Body-Boundary""; type=""multipart/related""

--RN-Http-Body-Boundary
Message-ID: <25845033.1160080657073.JavaMail.webmethods@exshaw>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related; type=""application/xml"";
  boundary=""----=_Part_235_11184805.1160080657052""

------=_Part_235_11184805.1160080657052
Content-Type: Application/XML
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Location: RN-Preamble
Content-ID: <1430586.1160080657050.JavaMail.webmethods@exshaw>"

//XML document begins here...

type AST =
| Document of AST list
| Header of AST list
/// ie. Content-Type is the tag, and it consists of a list of key value pairs
| Tag of string * AST list  
| KeyValue of string * string
| Body of string
```

The AST DU above could represent a first pass of the example data you posted in your other question.  It *could* be finer grained than that, but simpler is normally better.  I mean, the ultimate destination in your example is a Post type, and you could achieve that with some simple pattern matching.

Comment: I ended up going with a discriminated union, though I'm not sure I've designed it well. I've asked [a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26891564/f-fparsec-and-calling-a-stream-parser-recursively-second-take) based on this feedback and the feedback from [my second question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26875192/f-fparsec-and-updating-userstate). Thank you!