# F#, FParsec, and Calling a Stream Parser Recursively, Second Take

Tags: recursion, f#, multipart, fparsec

Thank you for the replies to [my first post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26853718/f-fparsec-and-calling-a-stream-parser-recursively) and [my second post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26875192/f-fparsec-and-updating-userstate) on this project. This question is basically the same question as the first, but with my code updated according to the feedback received on those two questions. How do I call my parser recursively?

I'm scratching my head and staring blankly at the code. I've no idea where to go from here. That's when I turn to stackoverflow.

I've included in code comments the compile-time errors I'm receiving. One stumbling block may be my discriminated union. I've not worked with discriminated unions much, so I may be using mine incorrectly.

The example POST I'm working with, bits of which I've included in my previous two questions, consists of one boundary that includes a second post with a new boundary. That second post includes several additional parts separated by the second boundary. Each of those several additional parts is a new post consisting of headers and XML.

My goal in this project is to build a library to be used in our C# solution, with the library taking a stream and returning the POST parsed into headers and parts recursively. I *really* want F# to shine here.

```
namespace MultipartMIMEParser

open FParsec
open System.IO

type Header = { name  : string
              ; value : string
              ; addl  : (string * string) list option }

type Content = Content of string
             | Post of Post list
and Post = { headers : Header list
           ; content : Content }

type UserState = { Boundary : string }
  with static member Default = { Boundary="" }

module internal P =
  let ($) f x = f x
  let undefined = failwith "Undefined."
  let ascii = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII
  let str cs = System.String.Concat (cs:char list)

  let makeHeader ((n,v),nvps) = { name=n; value=v; addl=nvps}

  let runP p s = match runParserOnStream p UserState.Default "" s ascii with
                 | Success (r,_,_) -> r
                 | Failure (e,_,_) -> failwith (sprintf "%A" e)

  let blankField = parray 2 newline

  let delimited d e =
      let pEnd = preturn () .>> e
      let part = spaces
                 >>. (manyTill
                      $ noneOf d
                      $ (attempt (preturn () .>> pstring d)
                                  <|> pEnd)) |>> str
       in part .>>. part

  let delimited3 firstDelimiter secondDelimiter thirdDelimiter endMarker =
      delimited firstDelimiter endMarker
      .>>. opt (many (delimited secondDelimiter endMarker
                      >>. delimited thirdDelimiter endMarker))

  let isBoundary ((n:string),_) = n.ToLower() = "boundary"

  let pHeader =
      let includesBoundary (h:Header) = match h.addl with
                                        | Some xs -> xs |> List.exists isBoundary
                                        | None    -> false
      let setBoundary b = { Boundary=b }
       in delimited3 ":" ";" "=" blankField
          |>> makeHeader
          >>= fun header stream -> if includesBoundary header
                                   then
                                     stream.UserState <- setBoundary (header.addl.Value
                                                                      |> List.find isBoundary
                                                                      |> snd)
                                     Reply ()
                                   else Reply ()

  let pHeaders = manyTill pHeader $ attempt (preturn () .>> blankField)

  let rec pContent (stream:CharStream<UserState>) =
      match stream.UserState.Boundary with
      | "" -> // Content is text.
              let nl = System.Environment.NewLine
              let unlines (ss:string list) = System.String.Join (nl,ss)
              let line = restOfLine false
              let lines = manyTill line $ attempt (preturn () .>> blankField)
               in pipe2 pHeaders lines
                        $ fun h c -> { headers=h
                                     ; content=Content $ unlines c }
      | _  -> // Content contains boundaries.
              let b = "--" + stream.UserState.Boundary
              // VS complains about pContent in the following line: 
              // Type mismatch. Expecting a
              //    Parser<'a,UserState>
              // but given a
              //    CharStream<UserState> -> Parser<Post,UserState>
              // The type 'Reply<'a>' does not match the type 'Parser<Post,UserState>'
              let p = pipe2 pHeaders pContent $ fun h c -> { headers=h; content=c }
               in skipString b
                  >>. manyTill p (attempt (preturn () .>> blankField))
                  // VS complains about Content.Post in the following line: 
                  // Type mismatch. Expecting a
                  //     Post list -> Post
                  // but given a
                  //     Post list -> Content
                  // The type 'Post' does not match the type 'Content'
                  |>> Content.Post

  // VS complains about pContent in the following line: 
  // Type mismatch. Expecting a
  //    Parser<'a,UserState>    
  // but given a
  //    CharStream<UserState> -> Parser<Post,UserState>
  // The type 'Reply<'a>' does not match the type 'Parser<Post,UserState>'
  let pStream = runP (pipe2 pHeaders pContent $ fun h c -> { headers=h; content=c })


type MParser (s:Stream) =
  let r = P.pStream s

  let findHeader name =
    match r.headers |> List.tryFind (fun h -> h.name.ToLower() = name) with
    | Some h -> h.value
    | None   -> ""

  member p.Boundary =
    let header = r.headers
                 |> List.tryFind (fun h -> match h.addl with
                                           | Some xs -> xs |> List.exists P.isBoundary
                                           | None    -> false)
     in match header with
        | Some h -> h.addl.Value |> List.find P.isBoundary |> snd
        | None   -> ""
  member p.ContentID = findHeader "content-id"
  member p.ContentLocation = findHeader "content-location"
  member p.ContentSubtype = findHeader "type"
  member p.ContentTransferEncoding = findHeader "content-transfer-encoding"
  member p.ContentType = findHeader "content-type"
  member p.Content = r.content
  member p.Headers = r.headers
  member p.MessageID = findHeader "message-id"
  member p.MimeVersion = findHeader "mime-version"
```

**EDIT**

In response to the feedback I've received thus far (thank you!), I made the following adjustments, receiving the errors annotated:

```
let rec pContent (stream:CharStream<UserState>) =
    match stream.UserState.Boundary with
    | "" -> // Content is text.
            let nl = System.Environment.NewLine
            let unlines (ss:string list) = System.String.Join (nl,ss)
            let line = restOfLine false
            let lines = manyTill line $ attempt (preturn () .>> blankField)
             in pipe2 pHeaders lines
                      $ fun h c -> { headers=h
                                   ; content=Content $ unlines c }
    | _  -> // Content contains boundaries.
            let b = "--" + stream.UserState.Boundary
            // The following complaint is about `pContent stream`:
            // This expression was expected to have type
            //     Reply<'a>    
            // but here has type
            //     Parser<Post,UserState>
            let p = pipe2 pHeaders (fun stream -> pContent stream) $ fun h c -> { headers=h; content=c }
             in skipString b
                >>. manyTill p (attempt (preturn () .>> blankField))
                // VS complains about the line above:
                // Type mismatch. Expecting a
                //     Parser<Post,UserState>    
                // but given a
                //     Parser<'a list,UserState>    
                // The type 'Post' does not match the type ''a list'

// See above complaint about `pContent stream`. Same complaint here.
let pStream = runP (pipe2 pHeaders (fun stream -> pContent stream) $ fun h c -> { headers=h; content=c })
```

I tried throwing in `Reply ()`s, but they just returned parsers, meaning `c` above became a `Parser<...>` rather than `Content`. That seemed to have been a step backwards, or at least in the wrong direction. I admit my ignorance, though, and welcome correction!

Comment: It seems that you want to define `pContent` as a parser function, i.e. as a function that returns a `Reply` value, but instead you return parser functions on both branches.

Comment: @StephanTolksdorf I tried throwing `Reply ()` in, but `c` then changed type from `Content` to `Parser<...>`. I admit my ignorance, but think that that's the wrong direction. Please correct me if I'm incorrect.

Comment: You can make your code compile by passing on the `stream` arg to `pContent` as an argument to the parser functions you construct on both branches. On the first branch you also have to wrap the `Post {...}` value in a list and then in a `Content.Post`. You can quickly see this by adding an explicit type annotation for the return type of `pContent`.

Comment: Note that constructing the parser functions on the fly as you do in  `pContent` can be quite inefficient. I'd recommend to split up the parser into components and then use `createParserForwardedToRef` to break up the direct recursion. I'd also recommend that you try to understand a bit how parser functions and combinators work under the hood (e.g. by reading the source or the user guide), which should make it easier for you to construct and debug parsers.

Comment: @StephanTolksdorf, thanks for the help. I'm scouring the User Guide and Reference for FParsec, but am reluctant to spend too much time digging into how it all works under the hood. Maybe it's just time to start digging...

Answer (score 0):

I can help with one of the errors.

F# generally binds arguments left to right, so you need to use either parentheses around the recursive calls to `pContent` or a pipe-backward operator `<|` to show that you want to evaluate the recursive call and bind the return value.

It's also worth noting that `<|` is the same as your `$` operator.

`Content.Post` is *not* a constructor for a Post object. You need a function to accept a Post list and return a Post. (Does something from the [List module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353738.aspx) do what you need?)

Comment: 1) I don't see how adding parentheses around the recursive call to `pContent` helps. I'll take the blame and say I'm being dense. Will you elaborate? 2) I was aware of the identity between `<|` and `$`. Coming from Haskell, I just think `$` is prettier and more concise. :) 3) What confuses me on your third point is that VS complains about a `Post` being `Content`. So I add a `Content` constructor, and it complains about a `Content` being a `Post`. But, I didn't see anything in `List` that jumped out as helpful. Since I define `Post` as `of Post list`, it seems like it should type check.

Comment: Actually, `<|` and `$` are not quite equivalent. F# `<|` is left-associative, while Haskell `$` is right-associative. So `f <| g <| x` is `f g x`, while `f $ g $ x` is `f (g x)`.

Answer (score 0):

My first answer was completely wrong, but I'd thought I'd leave it up.

The types `Post` and `Content` are defined as:

```ml
type Content =
    | Content of string
    | Post of Post list
and Post =
    { headers : Header list
    ; content : Content }
```

`Post` is a Record, and `Content` is a Discriminated Union.

F# treats the cases for [Discriminated Unions](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/discriminated-unions/) as a separate namespace from types. So `Content` is different from `Content.Content`, and `Post` is different from `Content.Post`. Because they are different, having the same identifier is confusing.

What is `pContent` supposed to be returning? If it's supposed to be returning the Discriminated Union `Content`, you need to wrap the `Post` record you are returning in the first case in the `Content.Post` case i.e.

```ml
$ fun h c -> Post [ { headers=h
                    ; content=Content $ unlines c } ]
```

(F# is able to infer that 'Post' refers to `Content.Post` case, instead of the `Post` record type here.)