# Defining an HTTP Multipart Post as a Recursive Datatype in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, multipart

I cannot wrap my head around how to define a type in Haskell that represents the recursive nature of an HTTP Multipart MIME POST.

In English, a Post is either a list of Headers along with Content of some type, or it's a list of Headers with Content of another Post. But Content can also be a list of Posts.

So I've defined `Header` thus:

```
data Header = Header { hName  :: String
                     , hValue :: String
                     , hAddl  :: [(String,String)] } deriving (Eq, Show)
```

I guess `Content` should be something like:

```
data Content a = Content a | [Post] deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Obviously, that fails: `parse error in constructor in data/newtype declaration: [Post]`

I've defined `Post` as:

```
data Post = Post { pHeaders :: [Header]
                 , pContent :: [Content] } deriving (Eq, Show)
```

I'm using Haskell to get a different perspective on my current task, the latest question thereon being [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26891564/f-fparsec-and-calling-a-stream-parser-recursively-second-take). Just using `String` for `Content`, I can parse simple POSTs using Parsec. But the goal is to parse complex Posts.

The link above, and the links found at that question, give the context for my current task. I'm a Haskell hobbyist, so please feel free to offer alternatives to the code I've posted here--I'm not married to it, and I'd love to learn. Ultimately, I'll use F#, unless I am unable to deliver, in which case I'll be forced to use C# and an imperative style. I welcome any wisdom or direction that supports a functional solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your datatypes make sense, your syntax is just wrong:

```
data Content a = Content a | Posts [Post a] deriving (Eq, Show)
```

You can name the `Posts` constructor whatever you like. However, you cannot have something like `pContent :: [Content]` - since content has a type variable, it must be applied to a type:

```
data Post a = Post { pHeaders :: [Header]
                   , pContent :: [Content a] } deriving (Eq, Show)
```

I would say that your approach is idiomatic Haskell.